# Trying to get property of non-object - Middleware - laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5, permisos, cuenta-usuario

Estimados, tengo un proyecto en Laravel 5.4 y tengo 3 tipos de usuarios (Administrador, personal y cliente)
Con el Administrador no tengo problemas, pero cuando asigno algunos metodos de algunos controladores al middleware de personal y trato de acceder a ellos, me arroja el error de la foto.[image: Imagen del error]

He probado con metodos y rutas con y sin parametros y con todos los intentos me arroja el mismo error.
Dejo el codigo de algunos archivos relacionados al middleware.

**Route/web**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['administrador','personal']], function(){
Route::resource('ot', 'OTController');
Route::resource('rol', 'RolController');
Route::resource('sucursal', 'SucursalController');
Route::resource('servicio', 'ServicioController');
Route::get('/servicio/crear/{id_ot}', 'ServicioController@crear')->name('servicio.create');
Route::get('/servicio/recuperar/{id}', 'ServicioController@recuperar')->name('servicio.recuperar');
Route::resource('mensaje', 'MensajeController');
Route::get('home', function(){
    return view('admin.home');
});
```

});

**Controller/Middleware/personal.php**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(Auth::user()->rol_id == 2) {
        return $next($request);
    }else{
        return route('login');
    }
}
```

Ademas tengo agregado el middleware tanto de administrador como el de personal y el de cliente en el kernel.php

```
'personal'      => \App\Http\Middleware\personal::class,
```

He revisado las rutas ("php artisan route:list") y efectivamente aparecen los metodos de los controladores con el permiso de administrador y de personal. Debo aclarar que solo a modo de prueba he otorgado los mismo permisos para adminitrador como para personal ya que en periodo de produccion solo algunos metodos de algunos controladores daran acceso a personal (eso ya lo tengo solucionado).

He buscado informacion, he probado variantes y he creado varias veces el middleware sin buenos resultados.

Si necesitan mas informacion me avisan y la agrego.

Quedo atento,
Gracias!

---

**Controller/Middleware/admin.php**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    if(Auth::user()->rol_id == 1) {
        return $next($request);
    }else{
        return route('login');
    }
}
```

Comment: No me queda del todo claro cuando funciona y cuando no.

Comment: Todo funciona bien con la cuenta de Administrador, pero cuando ingreso a una cuenta de personal, no tengo acceso a ningun metodo de ningun controlador, ya que arroja el error de la foto

Comment: ¿Pero usas dos middleware si entiendo bien?

Comment: Si, tengo uno para los administradores y otro para personal. Es el personal el que no funciona, aun cuando aplico "php artisan route:list" y me aparecen los middlewares de administrador y personal en los metodos de los controladores

Comment: ¿en qué consiste el middleware administrador que dices que sí funciona? puedes agregar su código?

Comment: Es igual al del personal, esta editado el tema principal con el codigo solicitado.

Comment: ¿versión exacta de Laravel?

Comment: la version de laravel es 5.4.24